# Error : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables: `RubricsDocument` and `Documents`. In the `RubricsDocument`, I have the id of the document (foreign key). My goal is to delete one document but the error

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

appears. I have try to delete rubrics of the document before the document but isn't work. I don't know what i have to do to resolve this error.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/204749 to see the creation of tables

```
RubricsDocument Table
-
1450    1   1   245 66
<-- 66 is id of the document    
1451    2   1   296 66    
1452    3   1   297 66    
1453    4   1   298 66    
1456    7   1   301 66
```

Comment: Post the CREATE statements of the 2 tables

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @SteveDiarrassouba you should update your question using [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of posting unreadable code in comments.

Comment: @SteveDiarrassouba edit your answer to include these statements you posted in comments and explain which  table is the parent table

Comment: Hi. Please act on all of [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code including input data & desired result & clear specification. Put both the code & the fiddle link in your post, make it self-contained. Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn how to contact a non-poster non-sole commenter using `@`. PS This is (obviously) almost surely going to be a faq, read many answers at hits googling your error message with & without your code's strings/names for the many possible reasons before you post. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have try to delete rubrics of the document before the document but
>   isn't work

It should work **unless** there is in this table a column that is also referenced by another table as a foreign key. When you first posted the `CREATE` statements in the comments, both tables had such references but the link you provided shows different statements.  
So if the link contains the actual `CREATE` statements you **can** delete the referenced rows first and then the row from `NETENTDOC`.  
But you could achieve what you want if you applied this: `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the `FOREIGN KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE `NETDOCRUB` (
    `NETIDDOCRUB` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `NETNUPOS` BIGINT(2) NOT NULL,
    `NETFGVISIBLE` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `NETIDRUB` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `NETIDENTDOC` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`NETIDDOCRUB`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`NETIDENTDOC`) REFERENCES `NETENTDOC` (`NETIDENTDOC`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

`ON DELETE CASCADE` takes care of the deletion of all "child" rows when a "parent" row is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply disable foreign key check which will allow you to delete the row of a table even if it is used a foreign key for some other tables.Check below query

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```